# Hide Edit button in Data View web part based on Person / Group column

Tags: data-view-web-part, edit-form, formatting

I am working on a customized Project Management solution using SharePoint. I have a data view web part which displays all the project data including Project Name / Project Manager. I have a Edit button in front of each line item which opens Edit Form for the respective line item. Each Items have a different Project Managers so I can not create clear permission groups in this case.

I want to show Edit button only for the Project Managers not for anyone else. Is there any way I can achieve this ?

Thanks in advance for your inputs !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creates two SharePoint groups, Project Managers and Project Users, then assign Contribute permission to Project Managers and read to Project Users.
This way, only Project Managers will be able to edit items.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry I didnt explain it clearly. Each line items have different Project Managers so I can not create a clear group or item level permission on each Item.

Comment: @Bhavesh why do you say you cannot assign item permission level on each item? I don't see why not

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Item level permissions becomes headache for the client because Project Managers keeps on changing on some of the projects. Also, SP2010 does not have any way to assign item level permissions thru SPD Workflow.

Comment: I was looking for a solution which can actually conditionally hide "Edit" button in Data View web part..so it shows edit button only to Project Manager.

Comment: SP/SPD 2010 DOES have an action to assign permission on items! You can see it only if you add an impersonation step. See this link http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-HA010376961.aspx#_Toc260924452